# c# IronPdf shuts down .NET 6 Web API under Linux Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, ironpdf

### Versions

- Separate .NET 6.0 Web API for PDF export
- IronPdf.Linux - 2022.5.5629
- IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Linux - 2022.5.5618

As of the date of writing the latest IronPdf Linux NuGet packages
[image]

### Problem

When I ran the .NET 6 Web API under Docker Linux Container the app shuts down itself when I hit the first method from IronPdf `this.pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync`. There is no error or going into the `catch` block, simply the app stops and I have to run it again.

### What have I tried? Code

I am following the official documentation provided by IronPdf: https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/

Here is my usecase and how I use IronPdf library:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("Reporting/PDF/{reportItemId:int}"]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerateReport(int reportItemId)
{
    try
    {
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.EnableDebugging = true;
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LogFilePath = "Default.log"; //May be set to a directory name or full file
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingMode = IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingModes.All;

        IronPdf.Installation.ChromeGpuMode = IronPdf.Engines.Chrome.ChromeGpuModes.Disabled;
        Installation.LinuxAndDockerDependenciesAutoConfig = false;
        IronPdf.Installation.Initialize();

        ReportItemViewModel reportItemViewModel = this.reportingManager.GetReportItemById(reportItemId); // Internal Logic
        List<PdfDocument> pdfDocs = new List<PdfDocument>();

        foreach (int itemsectionId in reportItemViewModel.ReportItemSectionIds)
        {
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = await CreatePDFDocument(itemsectionId);
            
            pdfDocs.Add(pdfDocument);
        }

        PdfDocument mergedPdfs = IronPdf.PdfDocument.Merge(pdfDocs);

        await AddFooterToPdfDocument(mergedPdfs);
        
        // ... getting mergedPdfs.Stream and uploading it

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.diagnosticService.AddErrorLog(ex: ex, accountId: accountId, employeeId: employeeId);
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In the code snippet above I've included the suggested Automatic Dependency Installation, Disable GPU Acceleration and "Ahead of Time" Initialization as stated in the IronPdf librabary.

The **first** method to be called from IronPdf librabry is inside the `CreatePDFDocument` method - `await this.pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync`:

```cs
private async Task<PdfDocument> CreatePDFDocument(int itemsectionId)
{
    try
    {
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.CssMediaType = PdfCssMediaType.Print;
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.PrintHtmlBackgrounds = true;
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.PaperOrientation = PdfPaperOrientation.Landscape;

        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.MarginLeft = 6.35;
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.MarginRight = 6.35;
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.MarginBottom = 12;

        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.Timeout = 120;
        this.pdfRenderer.RenderingOptions.HtmlHeader = new IronPdf.HtmlHeaderFooter
        {
            HtmlFragment = await this.viewRenderer.ConvertToStringAsync("Reports/_Header", itemsectionId)
        };

        string viewAsString =
           await this.viewRenderer.ConvertToStringAsync("Reports/ReportContainer", itemsectionId);

        PdfDocument pdfDocument = await this.pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync(
              viewAsString,
              new Uri(this.BaseUrl));

        return pdfDocument;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.diagnosticService.AddErrorLog(ex: ex, accountId: account.Id, employeeId: employeeId);
        throw;
    }
}
```

When we hit the `await this.pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync` method the app simply shuts down. We don't go in the `catch` block or throw error somewhere. I've tried to pass it very simple HTML like `<div><h1>Hello World, from IronPdf under Docker Linux</h1></div>` and the app shuts down again.

> Note: With the code flow given above, I've successfully extracted
> hundreds of PDFs. The problem only arises when trying to build and run
> the project with a Linux Docker image.

### Docker configuration

Right-clicking on the project and selecting `Add` -> `Docker support...` -> `Target OS` -> `Linux` creates the needed `Dockerfile`.
[image]

I am modifying the `Dockerfile` to match what IronPdf support provided in the link above. I am trying the one provided under the section `Debian Linux DockerFiles` -> `Debian 11 with .NET 6`.

```
# base runtime image (Debian 11 w/ .NET6 runtime)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 1433
EXPOSE 3306
# install necessary packages
RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y libgdiplus libxkbcommon-x11-0 libc6 libc6-dev libgtk2.0-0 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0 libdrm-common libgbm1 libasound2 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libxshmfence1
# update write permissions
RUN chmod 777 .
# base development image (Debian 11 w/ .NET6 SDK)
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
# restore NuGet packages
COPY ["Example.Export/Example.Export.csproj", "Example.Export/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Example.Export/Example.Export.csproj"
# build project
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Example.Export"
RUN dotnet build "Example.Export.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
# publish project
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Example.Export.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
# run app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Example.Export.dll"]
```

I am starting the project and everything runs normally:
[image]
[image]

Edit 1: I am providing the Docker logs exactly after calling the `await this.pdfRenderer.RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync` method after which the project stops. (Note: I am including the last X lines, as the whole log is really big and doesn't hold an error)

```
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Found job 2 in group 1 (of 1 groups)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Found job 2 in group 1 (of 1 groups)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Printing from browser to '/tmp/pdfzwqWbJ'
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Printing from browser to '/tmp/pdfzwqWbJ'
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Received browser print callback for path '/tmp/pdfzwqWbJ' (1)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Received browser print callback for path '/tmp/pdfzwqWbJ' (1)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Print finished for browser 2(success: 1)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Print finished for browser 2(success: 1)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Resolving job for browser 2 with 80743 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Resolving job for browser 2 with 80743 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f201403a860 from 80743 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f201403a860 from 80743 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Resolving job for browser 2 with 1 page document
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Resolving job for browser 2 with 1 page document
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Generating bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Generating bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully generated 80751 bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully generated 80751 bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Closing browser 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Closing browser 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Destroying browser (id:2)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Destroying browser (id:2)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Finished job 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Finished job 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Found job 2 in group 1 (of 1 groups)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Found job 2 in group 1 (of 1 groups)
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Job group 1 finished
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Job group 1 finished
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Job group 1 has overlays
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Job group 1 has overlays
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Retrieved 80751 bytes for job group 1 page 0 overlay 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Retrieved 80751 bytes for job group 1 page 0 overlay 2
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f201403a860 from 7745 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f201403a860 from 7745 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Applying overlay to page 0
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Applying overlay to page 0
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f202024d270 from 80751 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f202024d270 from 80751 bytes
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f202024d270
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f202024d270
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Generating bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Generating bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully generated 88299 bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully generated 88299 bytes for document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f201403a860
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully applied overlays
13:47:16 (139776153876224): Successfully applied overlays
13:47:16 (139776153876224): CefMessagePumpStd::Quit()
13:47:16 (139776892073728): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f2050020740
13:47:16 (139776153876224): CefMessagePumpStd::Quit()
13:47:16 (139776892073728): PdfDocumentFactory closed document 0x7f2050020740
13:47:16 (139776892073728): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f2050020740 from 88299 bytes
13:47:16 (139776892073728): PdfDocumentFactory created document 0x7f2050020740 from 88299 bytes
13:47:16 (139776892073728): Storing updated document 0
13:47:16 (139776892073728): Storing updated document 0
```

### Edit 1 - Temporary Solution

I was able to make a temporary solution to the problem as suggested in the comments by @ScottMildenberger. After changing the way I deploy to Azure it's working on production now.

Deploy to Azure App Service as Zip Deploy. The tricky part is that in the `Configuration` section in the App Service we have to change one application setting. Go to `Application Settings` and change `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to have a value of `0`. This gives the App Service `read` and `write` permissions. We do that because `IronPdf` is doing file operations behind the scenes and needs `write` access.
[image: WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE]
or if you are using Azure pipelines with YML:

```yaml
- task: AzureTask@4
  inputs:
    ... inputs ...
    appType: 'webApp'
    packageForLinux: 'path.zip'
    AppSettings: '-WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE 0'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'zipDeploy'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: false
```

---

I am still not able to run it under the Docker Linux container. In case I fix it, I will edit again with the solution.

Comment: Do you have any logs from your container?

Comment: This may be similar to a problem I had with IronPdf once in Azure App Service running Windows.  I was using IronPdf version 2022.1.4599 .Net Core 3.1.  IronPdf needs access to file system to write temporary files.  Due to how I was deploying in Azure Dev Ops the file system was read-only.  I was able to change to a different deploy option that made the file system writable and then it started working.  Found a comment on a post on this site that led me there....  I don't use Docker but do you have a writable file system when deploying that way?

Comment: @omajid I've edited the latest docker logs, thanks for writing back!

Comment: @ScottMildenberger Can you share how did you manage to successfully deploy the project holding IronPdf on Azure Dev Ops? Does deploying as an App Service work for you?

Comment: Have you also tried their support? From experience it's very good.

Comment: @JamesGould Thanks for writing back. I have, and we are still trying some bits for the last couple of days. Decided to bring the issue to a broader audience in case someone else has experienced the same issue and can help out. If we (IronPdf support and I) succeed to "fix" the issue I will update the question and let everyone know the solution asap.

Comment: @G.Dimov I changed our deploy in Azure Dev Ops to use 'Zip Deploy' which is not the default.  And yes, we have an API project running in an App Service that successfully uses IronPdf.  This issue had me stumped for a long time and the symptoms where similar to yours, no error messages I could find.  Once I change the Deployment Option it started working.

Comment: @G.Dimov here is the original post that led me to my solution, see the comments by Adam and darren on the first answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434693/c-sharp-pdf-generation-using-ironpdf-on-azure

Comment: Thanks, @ScottMildenberger. I can definitely try that as well.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger thanks for the information, I've edited the question. We have a working production as an App Service for the time being. If I make it work with Docker I will edit it again.

Answer (score 3):

The solution appears to be to use Docker from the command line. When using Visual Studio (17.0.2) on MacOS built-in debugger docker-compose launch setting, I ran into your same problem. However, when using Docker from the command line, it did not run into the problem, and I was able to repeatedly call "RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync" over and over without the program stopping execution. So, I think it has to do with some interaction with the debugger attached within the docker container.

I had sent an email to IronPdf support, and they responded with the following, which hopefully helps:

> We are aware of the issue described, and the following points may help to avoid (though not fix the situation):
>
> - Remove all debug break points
> - Run in release mode
> - Run Docker outside of Visual Studio (by Docker command-line)
> - Update Visual Studio

Comment: April 2023 and I still encountered this problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't normally read all comments, asnswer was there in Scott Mildenberger
comment.

If anyone facing issue with IronPdf.HtmlToPdf().RenderHtmlAsPdf(str) in Azure and using Azure Release Pipeline, check solution below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, we've figured out that it was heppning with long html fragments. I've solved it by **adding more resources to the pod** (In my case we've set 1Gi of memory, with a limit of 2Gi). However, with even bigger html fragments (5Gbs) the RenderHtmlAsPdfAsync method is never returning the pdf. By printing the html in the Edge browser, we got a document of 144 pages in a couple of minutes, so it is something inside IronPdf (2023.4.4) that is failing.