# Troubleshooting .NET 6.0 Azure Function App with IronPdf on Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, pdf-generation, ironpdf

I'm encountering an issue with a .NET 6.0 (LTS) Azure Function App on Windows, using the elastic premium plan. My application runs locally but not on Azure.  I'm following guidelines from IronSoftware on [How to Run HTML to PDF with .NET on Azure?](https://ironpdf.com/how-to/azure/) and insights from a related [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434693/c-sharp-pdf-generation-using-ironpdf-on-azure).  Initially, I considered .NET 6.0 (Isolated), but reverted due to [reported support issues](https://ironpdf.com/troubleshooting/debugging-azure-functions-on-local-machine-ironpdf/).

Here's where I'm at:

Local Development: The app runs locally on .NET 6.0 but had to copy the runtime to the bin directory.  I'm unsure if this step is necessary for a publish build or in the Azure environment, since its for Azureite local storage.

Testing: The app works as expected locally.

Deployment: I've used a publish profile, disabled 'run as package', and added extensive logging. However, the app fails on Azure when running the code from the Ironsoft example.

failing here:

```
log.LogInformation("About to render pdf...");
ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
using var doc = renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf("https://www.google.com/");
log.LogInformation("finished rendering pdf...");
```

example code:

```
log.LogInformation("Entered PrintPdf API function...");
        IronPdf.Installation.LicenseKey = "MYCOMPANYKEY"; 
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.EnableDebugging = false;
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingMode = IronPdf.Logging.Logger.LoggingModes.Custom;
        IronPdf.Logging.Logger.CustomLogger = log;
        Installation.LinuxAndDockerDependenciesAutoConfig = false;
        Installation.ChromeGpuMode = IronPdf.Engines.Chrome.ChromeGpuModes.Disabled;
        try
        {
            log.LogInformation("About to render pdf...");
            ChromePdfRenderer renderer = new ChromePdfRenderer();
            using var doc = renderer.RenderUrlAsPdf("https://www.google.com/");
            log.LogInformation("finished rendering pdf...");
            //return new FileContentResult(doc.BinaryData, "application/pdf") { FileDownloadName = "google.pdf" };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError(e, "Error while rendering pdf", e);
        }
```

Error Details:

| Type | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Entered PrintPdf API function... |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: About to render pdf... |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: ---------- Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.20348.0 (C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit\IronSoftware.log) ---------- |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Initializing local Chrome client... |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Using deployment directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating deployment candidates using root path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' (download: True) |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating folder deployments for win-x64 |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating embedded deployments for win-x64 |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating nuget deployments for IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating nuget deployments for IronPdf.Native.Chrome.Windows.Windows |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Attempting deployment for 'Chrome' 2023.11.0.20149 using 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Failed to locate assembly(s) for deployment 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' at path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: IronSoftware.Exceptions.IronSoftwareAssemblyMissingException: Failed to locate 'IronInterop' at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Successfully located 'IronInterop' at 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Determining deployment commands for platform 'Windows' v10.0.20348.0 |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Using deployment instructions for 'default' v |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Attempting to load Windows library 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronInterop.dll' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Attempting to load Windows library 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronInterop.dll' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Successfully loaded native library from 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronInterop.dll' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Successfully loaded 'IronInterop' version '2023.11.0.20149' from 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Successfully deployed 'Chrome' using 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Initializing Chrome renderer for OS Name: Windows, Identifier: win, Version: 10.0.20348.0, VersionName: , Domain: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Thread: .NET ThreadPool Worker, Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.27.5\64bit |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: Creating new job collection resource |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): ~ Chrome renderer v2023.11.0.20149~ |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): register JobManager as publisher for event_readyToInitializeNetworkEventsDevToolsHandler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): [EventRegistry] Register event_readyToInitializeNetworkEventsDevToolsHandler for a publisher |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): IsSingleProcess: 0 |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Creating Cef proxy controller |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Creating Cef interface |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new lifespan events |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new load handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new render handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new print handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new dev tools handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): JobManager subscribes a new sub, eventStr=event_readyToInitializeNetworkEventsDevToolsHandler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new dev tools registration factory |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new lifespan handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Assigning Cef proxy controller events... |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new lifespan events |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new load handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new render handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new print handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new dev tools handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): JobManager subscribes a new sub, eventStr=event_readyToInitializeNetworkEventsDevToolsHandler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new dev tools registration factory |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Created new lifespan handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Destroying Cef proxy event handler |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Assigning Cef proxy controller stream provider... |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Initializing Cef proxy controller |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Using subprocess path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronCefSubprocess.exe' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Using framework path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Using locales path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\locales' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Using resources path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native' |
| Trace | Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): Launching child process '"C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe" -ap -v -a -h -w -m -t -ta --browser-subprocess-path="C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\IronCefSubprocess.exe" --no-sandbox --lang=en-US --log-file=cef.log --log-severity=disable --resources-dir-path="C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native" --locales-dir-path="C:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\runtimes\win-x64\native\locales" --disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,WinUseBrowserSpellChecker,BackForwardCache MYAZUREFUNCTION v4.0 "\.\pipe\iisipm955547cf-bd85-45ba-a205-cfc9ce34ab42" "D:\DWASFiles\Sites\MYAZUREFUNCTION\Config\applicationhost.config" "D:\DWASFiles\Sites\MYAZUREFUNCTION\Config\rootweb.config" 0 |
| Trace | 1:11:53.244 PM Trace Severity level: Information, Message: 21:11:53 (4888): gpu_mode: '0' |

It looks like it fails on the subprocess launch in the second to last trace, but hard exits without hitting the try catch.

Given this context, I have one question:

What could be causing the IronPdf.ChromePdfRenderer to fail on Azure, despite functioning locally?
Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this line resolved a similar issue running in App Service:

```
IronPdf.Installation.SingleProcess = true;
```

This line forces chrome renderer to perform everything in the current process, rather than using subprocesses.  [Link to documentation](https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.Installation.html#IronPdf_Installation_SingleProcess)

Comment: It’d be useful to [edit] your answer to provide a bit more detail about what this line does as well as, if appropriate, a link to the documentation.